# WSO2 Message Broker Rest ApI Example

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I have used WSO2 Message broker for JSON data transfer one service to other many services (using Topic). When I connect to other services.

So I need to check that service availability.
connection loss
try again several time till connect service
server busy
if that server up later need call that service again
if not connection to service, alert message

For above purpose, if any way to configure in WSO2MB, WSO2ESB or any other service.

I have used following example for queue
https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Sending+and+Receiving+Messages+Using+Queues

Comment: I think you should explain your question a bit further.